# How to know number of users?

Tags: support

ust for curious I wanted to know how many users are there in superuser.com and Who is the 1st user?

If I click on the [users](https://superuser.com/users?page=272&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate) tab,it only shows me the new users details. But is it possible to know who is the 1st user and till now how many users are present.

Comment: First user is Jeff, the co founder of the [se] sites. http://superuser.com/users/1

Comment: @Sathya Thanks for replying.How to know how many users are there in superuser.com

Comment: on [users/sorted by reputation](http://superuser.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=all) you get 9 rows, 4 columns per page, so 36 users, multiplied by 5172. That should give you a rough idea. Also, I don't think that page shows unregistered users, so in reality there should be a lot more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) lets you run queries against a sanitised version of the database. The database is [up to a week out of date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77176/187228), so it should be good enough for your purposes. [A basic count for superuser](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/165633/number-of-users) returns 221877 at the time of this post (7th February 2014).

For something more up-to-date, you could use the [user query](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-types) on the [SE API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) with the [`total` filter](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters):

http://api.stackexchange.com/users?filter=total&site=superuser.com

This should be *almost* real-time - the API caches a little, but it's about as accurate as you'll be able to find.

Answer (score 3):

First user is Jeff Atwood, the co founder of the Stack Exchange sites.

- https://superuser.com/users/1

As for total number of users, all you can do is guesstimate - on [users/sorted by reputation](https://superuser.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=all) you get 9 rows, 4 columns per page, so 36 users, multiplied by 5172. That should give you a rough idea.

Also, I don't think that page shows unregistered users, so in reality there should be a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the [Stackexchange front door](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users) and list all sites sorted by the number of users. You'll find *Superuser* on rank #2 with 224k users. If you hover with your mouse over that number, it says right now **223,678 registered and unregistered users**. (This number is higher than the number I got from the data explorer's query, so I suppose the number is more up-to-date.)

Comment: Yup, SE's main site is more accurate, and Data Explorer should only be used for general statistics. I've also updated my answer with a SE API query that should be real-time (minus some caching), just in case anyone actually needs this information in a more script-friendly format.